# Script to remove text from .js files

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, shell

I need to write a bash script to remove some text from any `.js` file of my web project.
These are the elements I need to remove:

```
if ( Utils.DEBUGGING ) /* ... */ ;
if ( Utils.DEBUGGING ) {/* ... */}
if ( Utils.DEBUGGING ) {
 /* ... */
}

if (Utils.DEBUGGING) /* ... */ ;
if (Utils.DEBUGGING) {/* ... */}
if (Utils.DEBUGGING) {
 /* ... */
}

if (Utils.DEBUGGING ) /* ... */ ;
if (Utils.DEBUGGING ) {/* ... */}
if (Utils.DEBUGGING ) {
 /* ... */
}

if ( Utils.DEBUGGING) /* ... */ ;
if ( Utils.DEBUGGING) {/* ... */}
if ( Utils.DEBUGGING) {
 /* ... */
}
```

Any idea on how to do that?

I have started like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.js
do     
    # ...
done
```

Thanks

Comment: you want to remove all lines cotaining Utils.debugging or /* */ ? which patter are you trying to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any regex-based approach is going to struggle if the things inside the blocks contain any blocks themselves. I guess that you use /* ... */ as a placeholder for real code but I'm guessing that in reality your examples are more complex.

It's worth pointing out that if the flag is set to false, then there will be very little overhead when your code runs, as the compiler can do dead code elimination (DCE).

That said, if you really want to permanently get rid of these parts of your code, one option would be to use a tool such as [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). You can use it interactively online, via an API or as a standalone executable.

If you chose to go with the standalone option, your code could be something like this:

```
for file in path/to/input/*.js; do
    output_file=path/to/output/"$file"
    java -jar compiler.jar -O SIMPLE --js_output_file "$output_file" "$file"
done
```