# Remove text from JS File using a script

Tags: javascript, cmd

I am trying to write a script that will delete a line of code if it exists in the js file already. I am curious if this is even possible. When the script runs i want it to check if `user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf");` exists and then delete it if it does. This exists almost 100% percent of the time. So I am interested in knowing if it is possible or a command to remove it if it exists.

```
cd /D "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
echo user_pref("browser.cache.check_doc_frequency", 1);>>prefs.js
if (user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf"); !== undefined) {

}
```

I guess the catch is the js file already exists so its not like I can set it to a variable and then set the variable to nothing.

Not sure if this is possible any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378308/script-to-remove-text-from-js-files

Comment: Just to understand the question correctly, you're trying to write a bash script that removes a specific line if it exists in a file?

Comment: yes, firefox automatically has `user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf");` in there pref.js and i wanted to write a script to remove that line of code from being in that js file

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is remove a line with specific content from a file, then you can use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for that.

```
# Outputs into prefs.js.new all lines from prefs.js that do not include the string
grep -v 'user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf")' < prefs.js > prefs.js.new
mv prefs.js.new prefs.js
```

You can make it faster by looking for `'^user_pref(...` which tells `grep` to look for the pattern at the beginning of each line, so it will skip non-matching lines earlier.

If you are on Windows (judging from `cd /D "%APPDATA%...`) then you can use [`FIND`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx). I think you'd want to use `/v` to invert match:

```
FIND /v 'user_pref("...")' < prefs.js > prefs.js.new
```

You might need to play around with the quotation marks to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of deleting the original (which btw is not recommended by Mozilla), you would be better off overriding the option with custom preferences file: user.js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences

> In the profile directory are two user pref files: prefs.js and
>   user.js.  prefs.js is automatically generated by the application and
>   should not be edited manually, whereas user.js is an optional file the
>   user can create to override preferences initialized by other
>   preferences files.

So I would rather create the user.js file with this contents:

```
user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "");
```

In my (windows) case, the profile path is:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profilename}
```